# Remembering window's location and desktops on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, desktop

When I use my Mac, I like have a standard windows organization to do my Work:

- I put 4 consoles opened side by side on console 1
- I put Safari in other
- Mail and iCal in another
- TextMate on other
  etc

And depending on the work I do, I'd like to have different window configuration.
And when I have a external monitor connected, I need another configuration.

Is there any tool to make this? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: AppleScript would probably help, although it would be different depending on your exact needs.

Comment: I did not look around much for a tool, I just wrote my own AppleScript program to reposition some of my windows for when I connect an external monitor. If you are familiar with AppleScript, look into **position of window … of application process …** in *System Events*.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it but there is Layout V1.0:

http://www.andrewandoru.com/2009/02/08/labs-mac-os-x-application-layout/

Don't know if it is Spaces and/or multi-monitor aware though...

Answer (score 0):

[breeze](http://macendeavor.com/breeze) has global and application window states. the states can be triggered using they keyboard and are resolution independent. pair this with [sizeup](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup) and [windowflow](http://windowflow.com) and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0):

[Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) is another fine window management solution.